# OSerror [Winerror 126] the specified module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tensorflow, keras, openai-gym

I am doing reinforcement learning.
Running the Atari example causes an OSerror.

I use Win 10
and tensorflow 1.3, keras 2.2.2

```
import gym
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Reshape, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D

File "C:\Users\Lim\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
```

Why is this a problem? Where is the problem?

```
OSerror [Winerror 126] the specified module could not be found
```

I've looked into this, but I did not have a good answer.

Comment: Include the complete traceback in your question, then we will be able to tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> There is no windows support for the Atari environments at the moment

See the comment in this [thread](https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/11):

*I know a non-trivial number of people are currently using Gym on Windows. I think at this point, it mostly works (with the possible exception of Atari, though I think that too may be not too hard).
We don't have any Windows users at OpenAI currently. Is anyone on this thread interested in doing the work to get Gym fully supported on Windows (which mostly involves getting a CI service set up, and making sure our current functionality actually works there)? Happy to provide guidance.*

If your requirements allow you to do so, just switch environments, classic control environments work like a charm under windows:

```
env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
```